# C#: Build List of years as integers

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'd like to create a C# `List` of integers, from say 1930 to 2010. Off the top of my head, the only way I can think of to do this is to use a `for` or `while` loop to loop through each integer between the numbers and add them to the `List` individually.

I know C# lists have a lot of interesting methods, especially when you're using Linq. Can anyone think of a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, why are you creating these years? so we can give better suggestions.

Comment: Using a while\for loop will be efficient. Re-using the result is likely to be more important from an efficiency point-of-view, rather than how it is created.

Comment: @chibacity, I'm building the values to use in a drop-down select list in HTML, so there's probably not much need to worry how the List will be used.

Comment: Ah, I see - you mean efficiency as in "less code", rather than "better performing".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(1930, 81)` ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)) will get you an enumerable containing what you want. The first parameter is the starting value and the second is the number of items. You need 81 instead of 80 because you want 1930 to 2010 inclusive.

If you explicitly want it as a `List`, use `Enumerable.Range(1930, 81).ToList()`.

This method is probably no different in terms of efficiency, but is more succinct code.

Comment: +1.  It better documents intent, is more declarative than imperative, and is less prone to screw-ups, like accidentally modifying loop variables.  An aside: I wish there was a Range-like function that took the lower and upper bound, rather than the lower bound and count.  Not sure what you'd call it, or how to deal with the inclusive/exclusive naming/usage problem, tho :)

Comment: @Merlyn: yes, I'd agree. Something akin to F#'s [1930..2010] syntax would be nice.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Enumerable.Range()`

```
var MyList = Enumerable.Range(1930, 2010-1930+1).ToList();
```

Comment: Couldn't I just do `new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1930, 2010-1930+1))` and avoid the loop?

Comment: @Mega: What loop?  Any loop in his code will exist in your code, too (copying the enumerable to a list).

Comment: @Merlyn: I changed my answer.  Originally it had a loop in it.

Answer (score 10):

The other two answers are correct, using `Enumberable.Range()` is the quick/easy way to do this, but I would add on piece. Use `DateTime.Now.Year` so you don't have to fix the code every year. In two months, using a hard-coded value for the second parameter would have made this out of date.

```
List<int> listYears = Enumerable.Range(1930, DateTime.Now.Year - 1930 + 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

So, while this has been answered (with good answers), why not *create* a methods which 'yields' [(a generator method)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java#Generator_methods) -- `Enumerable.Range` is just such a method that is standard:

```
IEnumerable<int> InclusiveRange(int s, int e) {
   for (int i = s; i <= e; i++) {
     yield return i;
   }
}

var r = InclusiveRange(1930, 2010).ToList();
```

Happy coding.

Comment: I would have combined it with **jb.** answer : `var r = InclusiveRange(1930, DateTime.Now.Year - 1930 + 1).ToList();` :)

Comment: @Noctis No need to subtract the start year; just `var r = InclusiveRange(1930, DateTime.Now.Year).ToList();`